# How to use IF formula?

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

How to use IF for these numbers?

[image]

=IF(G2<2,"5")

I only can do the first 1 to 2 result will be 5, the rest I have no idea how to add it in if formula.

Comment: As an alternative you can also do this: `=MIN(20,INT((G2+1)/2)*5)`.

Comment: Or also `=VLOOKUP(G2,{1,5;3,10;5,15;7,20},2,TRUE)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `IF` function takes *three* parameters, the first is what condition to check, followed by the positive case, then followed by the else negative case.  Perhaps you want something like this:

```
=IF(G2 < 2, "5", IF(G2 < 4, "10", IF(G2 < 6, "15", "20")))
```